# Java - String Index Out of Bounds Exception : 11

Tags: java, string, exception

I am writing a simple program to get the first initial of the last name.

`input: Bruce Lee`
`output: L`

Here is the code:

```
public char getFirstInitial()
    {
        char initial;
        int num = this.getFullName().length();

        while (this.getFullName().charAt(num) != ' ')  //this is line 120
        {
                num--;
        }
        initial = this.getFullName().charAt(num + 1);

        return initial;
    }


public String getFullName()
    {
        return fullName;
    }
```

I'm getting this error:

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 11
    at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
    at lab1.Person.getFirstInitial(Person.java:120)
```

I don't get what the problem is. Thank you

Comment: `int num = this.getFullName().length()-1;` Also you can read the doc of `charAt`. _"Returns the char value at the specified index. An index ranges **from 0 to length() - 1**"_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't forget indexes are 0 based. So the first element is at index 0 and last is at lenght -1

You could also check for the index being >= 0 in that loop, in case the specified name is invalid.

Comment: Thanks!!  solved it by adding -1

`int num = this.getFullName().length() - 1;`

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
int num = this.getFullName().length();
```

to

```
int num = this.getFullName().length() - 1;
```

As indexes start from 0 and go till string.length()-1.

Answer (score 0):

name.charAt(num) will throw the exception bcoz index will be 1 less than total length .

Update the code

```
while (name.charAt(num-1) != ' ')  //this is line 120
        {
                num--;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In java there are always problems arisses when you perform index wise operations on a string therefore firstly you should convert the stricng into character array then you should perform operations, as the others described above if you use length()-1 instead of length() then array out of bounds error would be remove.